# Suggest a BPM like tool to automate unattended operations with minimal human involvement

Tags: workflow, business-process-management

a system needs to facilitate file processing, database operations and report generation based on unique client-to-client business rules fully automated along with typical BPM human-to-human workflows.

BPMs tend to drift towards the latter. I struggle to find a vendor providing solution for the former.

Low code is a requirements.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Interfacing released the [enterprise management system](https://www.interfacing.com/enterprise-management-system), which looks like a good fit for [enterprise process](https://www.interfacing.com/enterprise-process).

EPC's centralized repository stores and manages processes and related information within a user-friendly and intuitive environment. There are some features including the ability to build processes focused on data, the rapid delivery of applications through low or no-code platforms, and mobile-friendly applications.

You could use the free trial to save your money.